# how to set export command for apache user

Tags: apache, export

I'm developing a site where I need to use a program but I have to export one VAR, so ok by command line in my user it's easy, 
export MY_VAR=/PATH

The problem is when try to execute the same program through the website I got an error telling me this:
**Set environment variable $MY_VAR to the location**

I've try to execute a script, but I think the problem is set the variable but with my user, I mean, I've try to do this in php:

```
echo exec('sh /PATH/exportscript.sh');
```

Also this:

```
$cmd = "export";
$path="MY_VAR=/PATH/data_tables/";
$export= $cmd . " " . $path;
shell_exec($export);
```

No result with this command....any other option? How I can put MY_VAR for Apache???